# Adding the title of the song in a sentence or question

Tags: nouns

I am trying to find out how to say "I sang a song called something yesterday".

I do know how "I sang a song yesterday" is translated to Japanese which is
昨日は歌を歌いました

But where should I put the title of the song in question in the sentence?

Is it 昨日は歌という"title"を歌いました?

So I ask here how to ask for the title of a thing and maybe work something out from there.

P.S. It's a bit hard to google "Title of a song" or "Name of a song" in Japanese :D

Comment: "Song title" is [曲名](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%9B%B2%E5%90%8D) in Japanese.

Comment: @AndrewT. Can you direct me to a site where they have usage example? I'll add it to my list of resource. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is to insert the song title in the Japanese quotation marks 「」.

So, "a song called 'XXX'" would be:

> 「XXX」という曲{きょく} or
>
> 「XXX」という歌{うた}

Note that it is ***ungrammatical*** to say:

> 歌という"title"

because that means "the title by the name of ’歌’", which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

name という item - "item" called "name"